# JQuery, regular update of a DIV section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do display time-changing data on a web page. I use the JQuery framework. I use the following code as a test : display a different random number each second. It does not work. Why ? What is a correct, working way ?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
          function refreshRandomNumber() {
            var lHtmlBlob = "<p> random = " + Math.random() + "</p>";
            $('#random_number').html(lHtmlBlob);
          }
        setInterval(refreshRandomNumber(), 1000);
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="random_number"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `setInterval` just the function referenced by `refreshRandomNumber` and not the return value of that function what you do by using `refreshRandomNumber()`. So try this:

```
setInterval(refreshRandomNumber, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly now. I started to learn JavaScript two hours ago, my first gotcha ^^

Answer (score 2):

Small difference. instead of:

```
setInterval(refreshRandomNumber(), 1000);
```

use:

```
setInterval(refreshRandomNumber, 1000);
```

That passes the function rather than the function return value.